# Set IBMQ to qiskit-ibm-runtime

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

I have the following code in which I provide an API-key and set `ibmq` dict.

```python
ibmq = {'token':'',
            'hub':'ibm-q',
            'group':'open',
            'project':'main'}
```

after setting `ibmq`, I pass it to the following function

```python
evaluate(circuit_cases=circuit_cases,eval_mode=eval_mode,num_nodes=1,num_threads=4,early_termination=[1],ibmq=ibmq)
```

after that, I take these values as following

```
token=ibmq['token'],hub=ibmq['hub'],group=ibmq['group'],project=ibmq['project']
```

I have question about how to set in `qiskit-ibm-runtime`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. What exactly is your question? What are you trying to do with `qiskit-ibm-runtime`?

Comment: i want to run the qiskit code with qiskit-ibm-runtime not with IBMQ LOADER AND SAVE ACCOUNT.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**: Most of your questions will likely be answered here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/quantum-computing?topic=quantum-computing-get-started

---

If you are using IBM Cloud, you will have to first create a Runtime instance, which will have an associated `instance-key`. Additionally, you will also need your account's `token`.

Once you have installed Qiskit Runtime with `pip install qiskit-ibm-runtime`, you need to make use of the `QiskitRuntimeService` function in the following way

```
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService

service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel = "ibm_cloud", token = token, instance = instance-key)
```

Once you have access to the service, you can send jobs for execution using the Qiskit primitives `Sampler` and `Estimator` (see additional info here: https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/v2-primitives) in the following way

```
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Sampler, Session

with Session(service=service, backend='your_device') as session:
     sampler = Sampler()
     job = sampler.run(your_circuit)
     result = job.result()
     session.close()
```

There is of course plenty of room for further customisation, which you can find by exploring the link above.